# Progress bar returns infinity in php ajax download file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i want to show a progress bar while user download a file my javascript code returns infinity, and i need the percentage no to track my progressbar. have searched online since i seem not to be lucky to get this resolve.

this the js code below

```
var _OBJECT_URL;

var progress = document.getElementById("progress");


 var progressText = document.getElementById("progress-text");

// Call an AJAX

document.querySelector('#form-download').addEventListener('submit', function() {


var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
    if(request.readyState == 2 && request.status == 200) {
        // Download is being started
    }
    else if(request.readyState == 3) {
        // Download is under progress
    console.log('downloading');
    }
    else if(request.readyState == 4) {
    console.log("download")
        // Downloaing has finished

        
        
        // Recommended : Revoke the object URL after some time to free up resources
        // There is no way to find out whether user finished downloading
        // setTimeout(function() {
        //  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(_OBJECT_URL);
        // }, 60*1000);
    }
});

request.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    var percent_complete =  (e.loaded / e.total);
    console.log(percent_complete);
  document.getElementById("progress").value = percent_complete;
});

request.responseType = 'blob';

// Downloading a JPEG file
request.open('post', 'backup_log.php'); 

request.send();
```

});

this is my html code

```
       <form id="form-download" method="POST">

          <center>

            <div class="btn" style="display: block">

            <!-- HTML !-->

            <button class="button" name="submit" role="button">Download</button>
           
          </div>
          <span style="margin-top: 10px" class="loader"> </span>
          <progress id="progress" value="" ></progress>
          <span id="progress-text"></span>
          </center>
        </form>
```

Comment: You’re not checking the `lengthComputable` property as the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/total) is suggesting.

Comment: ok Sebastian thanks, have checked the length computable and its dosn't return the infinity anymore. however the value of total is zero i only get the value of loaded. can you still help out?